# (command line) tool to assemble graphics

Tags: graphics, plot

I am looking for any command line tool/software, able to assemble graphics in a smart way, and possibly to crop.
Imagick/Montage is an option, but it is surely not the best one to create structured multi-graph figures, especially when each subplot has different sizes.

Thank you.

Comment: what file format? is that not important? is the way it's assembled, presented not important either?

Comment: any file format (jpeg, png, pdf). let's say that I have few figures and they should be "smartly" assembled, some level of control should be there, e.g. order / how many per line ... the program should just automatically resize each of them in the best way...

Comment: you're talking about some google-level neural network. what makes you think such software would be free?

Comment: well .... I partially disagree. Basically if you have 4 plots and you impose: to be  2x2 and a maximum output width , you just need to tile and resize them.  That's all about. Montage actually does something like that, but it becomes absolutely complicated if the figures have different sizes and proportions - at least for what I know. I guess I could just script it ...

Comment: yeah you probably should. Also your need is ill-defined in your question...